# XML Schema - how to add "type=xs:string" into a complex element?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I got the following XML String:

```
<dyn_banner>
    <pattern>header.jpg</pattern>
    <param id='1'>attributes[123]</param>
    <param id='2'>attributes[456]</param>
    <param id='X'> etc. 
    <param id='X'> counting ...
.
.
.

 </dyn_banner>
```

This is what I managed to produce in XSD so far:

```
<xs:element name="dyn_banner">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="pattern" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="param" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
```

My problem now is that it's not clear for me how to tell the XML Schema that the element "param" does include a string (here: attributes[123 etc.].

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the main problem.
The string between the -tags is defined by simpleContent & extension-tags:

```
<xs:element name="dyn_banner">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="pattern" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="param" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
                <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
```

The ID's can be of the same number still, that's something I need to figure out in the next step.

Comment: Re keeping the IDs distinct - you can do this with an `xs:unique` at the level of the `dyn_banner` element.